# How to revert styles on second click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my script:

```
function panelShow(index, code) {
    buttons.forEach(function(button){
        button.style.borderBottom="";
    });
    tabButtons[index].style.borderBottom="none";
    panels.forEach(function(panel){
        panel.style.display="none";
    });
    panels[index].style.display="block";
    panels[index].style.backgroundColor=code;
}
```

The `panelShow()` takes parameters like `index` and `code` (code of the color). For example `panelShow(1, #0000);`

If there is a second click I want to revert styles and make `panels[index].style.display="none";`

How to do so? Please VanillaJS only.

Thanks.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework, sorry. Show a minimal effort in your question.

Comment: I did.. wrote the above script @JorgeFuentesGonzález

Comment: Please include a [MCVE], HTML often provides important context for javascript questions. From your code we have no idea what `buttons`, `tabButtons` and `panels` are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try (answer is for [this version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56012664/1) of question)

```js
let panels = [...document.querySelectorAll('.panel')];
panels.map(e=> e.ondblclick = e=> e.target.style.display="none" );

function panelShow(index, code) {
    // ...your code
    panels[index].style.display="block";
    panels[index].style.backgroundColor=code;
}

panelShow(0,"#ff0000");
```

```html
<div class="panel">panel 1 contetn</div>
<div class="panel">panel 2 contetn</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it on second click.